# How to patch public int "set" method though Harmony Patches

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to patch public int "set" method taught Harmony Patches. The method I want to patch is a 7D2D function (ProgressionValue.Level). I wrote a little patch, but It doesn't work.
Method I want to patch:

```cs
    public void set_Level(int value)
    {
        this.calculatedFrame = -1;
        if (this.ProgressionClass == null)
        {
            this.level = value;
            return;
        }
        if (this.ProgressionClass.IsSkill)
        {
            this.level = this.ProgressionClass.MaxLevel;
            return;
        }
        this.level = value;
    }
```

Method I wrote:

```cs
    using HarmonyLib;
    using UnityEngine;

    namespace Undead_InstantSkillLeveling
    {
        [HarmonyPatch(typeof(ProgressionValue))]
        [HarmonyPatch(nameof(ProgressionValue.Level))]
        public class Udead_Harmony_InstantSkill
        {
            private static void Prefix(ProgressionValue __instance)
            {
                __instance.Level = __instance.ProgressionClass.MaxLevel;
            }
        }
    }
```

Harmony used: [Harmony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtOzO.png)

Comment: "but I dunno will it work, or not" - have you tried it?

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: So please detail the problem. Here's a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask